# android:animateLayoutChanges not working in RecyclerView when changing maxLines of TextView

Tags: android, animation, textview, android-recyclerview

I have a simple setup: a `RecyclerView` shows a list of items, each containing several `TextView`s. One of the text views can have multiple lines, initially I have `android:maxLines` set to 1. In item's click listener I am toggling it between max 1 lines and max infinite (to show full content). It works fine except it is not animated. I tried to add `android:animateLayoutChanges` to different levels in my view hierarchy, but still no animation.

Please let me know your thoughts on this.

**NOTE:** I can program a manual animation, but I want Android to handle it for me with this xml property.

---

**SOME OF MY CODES:**

My list item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rootCard"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/destination"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="36dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textSize="25sp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/editButton"
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_edit"
                android:contentDescription="@string/edit_button_content_descr"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dateRange"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="17sp" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/daysLeft"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/days_left_background"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/comments"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

In my view holder I am expanding `comments` TextView:

```
    rootCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            comments.setMaxLines((comments.getMaxLines() == 1) ? Integer.MAX_VALUE : 1);
        }
    });
```

Here is the layout of my fragment containing the RecyclerView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/common_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/common_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/common_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/common_vertical_margin"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/tripList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:listitem="@layout/list_item_trip" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't call `notifyItemChanged()` of the adapter, so Android doesn't know that something was changed and should be animated. So all you need is to add this method call after you change your `maxLines` property:

```
rootCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        comments.setMaxLines((comments.getMaxLines() == 1) ? Integer.MAX_VALUE : 1);
        notifyItemChanged(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
    }
});
```

If it wouldn't work try to set `animateLayoutChanges` to the root view of layout - in your case it's `CardView`.